# angularjs GET 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, angularjs

I can't seem to solve what's wrong in my code
It doesn't really specify anything with telling me that the error is on line 1 in php(this must be false).
I have double checked my sql server information and it seems to be correct,
but the test server im using online is very slow, so could that be the case,
not loading fast enough? (but its deff working in my sql express management)
I would appreaciate the help very much

**Here is my html:**

```
   <html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="cntrl">
<form>
Student ID: <input type="text" ng-model="id" name="id" ng-disabled="obj.idisable">
Student Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="id">
<input type="button" value="{{btnName}}" ng-click="insertdata()" >
{{msg}}

</form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Roll No</th>
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="student in data">
                <td>{{student.studid}}</td>
                <td>{{student.studname}}</td>
                <td><button ng-click="deleteStud(student.studid);">Delete</button></td>
                <td><button ng-click="editStud(student.studid, student.studname);">Edit</button></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('cntrl', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.obj={'idisable':false};
    $scope.btnName="Insert";

    $scope.insertdata=function(){
        $http.post("insert.php",{'id':$scope.id, 'name':$scope.name, 'btnName':$scope.btnName})
        .success(function(){
            $scope.msg="Data Inserted";
            $scope.displayStud();

        })

    }

    $scope.displayStud=function(){
        $http.get("select.php")
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.data=data
        })
    }
    $scope.deleteStud=function(studid){
        $http.post("delete.php",{'id':studid})
        .success(function(){
                $scope.msg="Data Deletion successfull";
                $scope.displayStud();


        })

    }

    $scope.editStud=function(studid, studname)
    {
        $scope.id=studid;
        $scope.name=studname;
        $scope.btnName="Update";
        $scope.obj.idisable=true;
        $scope.displayStud();

    }

});


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**And here is my select.php:**

```
<?php
//database settings
include "connectdb.php";

$query="select * from student";
//$data = array();
$rs=$dbhandle->query($query);

while ($row = $rs->fetch_array()) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

    //print_r($data);

    return json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: an error 500 is a server error. Your error is in your php code, add debg infos to find where your error is thrown

Comment: you may check your nginx/apache or php-fpm logs.

Comment: You cannot return encoded data, Your code does not run inside the method. So change: `return json_encode($data);` to `echo json_encode($data);`  You can see that fi You add: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  to top of Your script.